# jQuery plugin for simple ul show/hide rotation

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a simple plugin to rotate (in the sense of looping through and replacing) a list of elements.

say i have:

```
<ul class="rotate-this">
  <li>element 1</li>
  <li>element 2</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

i would like a plugin that i will use like this:

```
$('.rotate-this').rotate({interval: 300});
```

and it show/hide the next element in the list every 300 milliseconds.
there has to be something, but i couldn't find it...

Answer (score 1):

check this: http://jsfiddle.net/mSmbv/

```
 function run() {
        //$("li").click(function() {  
        var prev = $(".rotate-this li:first-child");
        $.unique(prev).each(function(i) {
          $(this).delay(i*600).slideUp(function() {
            $(this).appendTo(this.parentNode).slideDown();
          });
        });
      //});
    }

    window.setInterval(run,1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own function like this

```
$.fn.rotate = function (obj) {
    $items = this.children();
    window.cnt = 0;
    if (obj.start == true) {
        window.rotInt = setInterval(function () {
            cnt == $items.length ? cnt = 0 : ++cnt;
            $items.eq(cnt).show().siblings().hide();
        }, obj.time);
    } else {
        clearInterval(window.rotInt);
    }
}
$('.rotate-this').rotate({
    time: 1000,
    start: true
});
```

To end the rotate set start to false like this

```
$('.rotate-this').rotate({
    time: 1000,
    start: false
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/53pRw/1/)